# Find the Mean of a Value by Year (not the whole date)

Tags: r, date

I'll preface this by saying I'm very much a self taught beginner with R.

I have a very large data set looking at biological data.
I want to find the average of a variable "shoot.density" split by year, but my date data is entered as "%d/%m/%y". This means using the normal way I would achieve this splits by each individual date, rather than by year only, eg.

```
tapply(df$Shoot.Density, list(df$Date), mean)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am also happy to paste in a section of my data, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in date-class, you can use `format` to transform your date column to a year variable:

```
tapply(df$Shoot.Density, list(format(df$Date, '%Y')), mean)
```

If it is in the format `%d/%m/%y`, you need the substr function:

```
tapply(df$Shoot.Density, list(substr(df$Date,7,8)), mean)
```

You can also do this with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(years = format(df$Date, '%Y')) %>% 
  summarise(means = mean(Shoot.Density))
```

Another way to do this is with the year function of the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mean(Shoot.Density), by = year(Date)]
```

Comment: Thank you for all the options, I've used a couple in different situations and it works a charm.